# How can we know what phrases visitors search for on before visiting our site and which search terms we rank on the first page in Google?

Tags: seo, google, keywords, search-terms

1. To visit our site, what phrases have visitors searched for on Google? How do I know?
2. How do I know than What words do we have on Google's first page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This can be easily seen if you connect your site to google webmaster accounts for google and bing webmaster account for yahoo/bing. They will show the results under search queries.
2. In tools such as Ahrefs, Semrush, Serpstat when you insert the domain it will show the keywords ranking according to their database's reach.

Comment: for 1 answer: From which part? and for 2 answer: Is it possible on Google webmaster?

Comment: 1: You have go to Search Traffic > Search Analytics. 2:It will show limited results and also not semrush gives around 5 scans with limited results a day so you can check it through that too.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Search Console under Performance: you can choose pages then check queries for each page.